# Check empty method body and empty Class in Java on SonarQube rule

Tags: java, class, methods, sonarqube

Im trying to create a SonarQube rule that will check for methods with empty body and classes without implementation (empty class).In my project there are folders line "test", "apiTest" ect so, I need to find the way to check those folders for empty methods, tests ect. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: it's in default rules. isn't it?

Comment: Those are avalaible in SonarJava : https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1186 and https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2094

Comment: Explore the API Class. For eg: Class c1 = AnyName.class; Further you can call c1.getMethods(), c1.getFields() etc.. Compare the result and work on a bit logic...